# Read XML and Convert into RegEx String Array

Tags: c#, xml, regex

This is the fixed code for RegEx Pattern. this is perfectly working fine. i want the same format from XML file. Each and every time i cant able to edit the code, so only i try to use this type of method.

```
Regex[] regPatterns = { new Regex(@"\[(.*?)\]"),
                        new Regex(@"\'_(.*?)\'") 
                      };
```

Sample XML is Here

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
    <RegExPattern>
        <Pattern name="DateFormat">
            @"\[(.*?)\]"
        </Pattern>
        <Pattern name="NumberFormat">
            @"\d+"
        </Pattern>
    </RegExPattern>
```

Sample C# Code is Here

```
regPatterns = ReadRegExPatterns();

private Regex[] ReadRegExPatterns()
    {
        using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("RegExFormats.xml"))
            {
                while (reader.Read())
                {
                    if (reader.IsStartElement())
                    {
                        switch (reader.Name)
                        {
                            case "Pattern":
                                if (reader.Read())
                                {
                                    //Error Line
                                    regPatterns = new Regex(reader.Value.Trim());
                                }
                                break;
                        }
                    }
                }
            }

        return regPatterns;
    }
```

I struck to convert to regex[] format, help me.

Answer (score 0):

First, you didn't define the `regPatterns` variable inside the method, you need to define it, and since you're doing a `return regPatterns`, it needs to be the same type than the return of your method (`Regex[]`).

But creating a method that returns an array is a relatively bad idea (it breaks encapsulation by giving away a detail of implementation), it would be better to return, for example, an IEnumerable which is the "to-go" class when returning a collection of something in .Net.

Added bonus, it makes it possible to use the yield keyword to implement your method really easily:

```
private IEnumerable<Regex> ReadRegExPatterns()
{
    using (XmlReader reader = XmlReader.Create("RegExFormats.xml"))
    {
        while (reader.Read())
        {
            if (reader.IsStartElement())
            {
                if (reader.Name == "Pattern")
                {
                    if (reader.Read())
                    {
                        yield return new Regex(reader.Value.Trim());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.